# WCF application hang (WinDBG output attached)

Tags: c#, wcf, windbg, freeze

We have a problem with a WCF service, that we can't reproduce. From time to time, the service doesn't respond to calls made by clients. This happens more often on mondays, after some time of inactivity.

The WCF service is self-hosted in a windows service. The instance context is per call. It uses `NetTcpBinding` without security, and the whole WCF configuration is done in code, no XML configuration. We have set the `ServiceThrottle` parameters to 1024 for sessions, calls, and instances. Here is the full `ServiceHost` configuration:

```
    ServiceThrottlingBehavior throttle;
    throttle = _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Find<ServiceThrottlingBehavior>();
    if (throttle == null)
    {
        throttle = new ServiceThrottlingBehavior();
        throttle.MaxConcurrentCalls = 1024;
        throttle.MaxConcurrentSessions = 1024;
        throttle.MaxConcurrentInstances = 1024;
        _svcHost.Description.Behaviors.Add(throttle);
    }

    ...

    TimeSpan timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5);

    NetTcpBinding binding = new NetTcpBinding(SecurityMode.None);
    binding.OpenTimeout = timeout;
    binding.CloseTimeout = timeout;
    binding.ReceiveTimeout = timeout;
    binding.SendTimeout = timeout;
    binding.MaxBufferSize = 10485760;
    binding.MaxReceivedMessageSize = 10485760;

    XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas quotas = new XmlDictionaryReaderQuotas();
    binding.ReaderQuotas = quotas;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxStringContentLength = 10485760;
    binding.ReaderQuotas.MaxArrayLength = 10000;

    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = MessageCredentialType.None;

    ...

    ServiceEndpoint endpoint = _svcHost.AddServiceEndpoint(intfType, binding, serviceBaseAddress + "/" + intfType.Name);
    endpoint.Behaviors.Add(new ClientTrackerEndpointBehavior());
```

The problem shows up with an exception thrown at a client. Between 5 and 10 clients are connected to the service, and every one throws this type of exception (even a client that runs on the same machine as the service itself):

```
System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException
  The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:00:29.9969997'.
  An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
StackTrace:
   at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Send(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.Write(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, Boolean immediate, TimeSpan timeout)
```

After the exception was thrown, we tried to connect to the service manually using `telnet`, and it seemed that this connection attempt is refused also. Since we had the problem this monday with 3 of our customers on production systems that we cannot attach the Visual Studio debugger to, we created user mini dumps with WinDBG to analyze the problem. The first thing we checked was the current values of the `ServiceThrottle` (only one dump here, but the output is equivalent to the output generated with the other dumps):

```
    0:032> !dumpheap -type ServiceThrottle -short
    01fb65a4 

    0:032> !do 01fb65a4 
    Name:        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ServiceThrottle
    MethodTable: 70cc56f0
    EEClass:     70a07ce4
    Size:        40(0x28) bytes
    File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    70cc572c  400314f        4 ...cher.FlowThrottle  0 instance 01fb6660 calls
    70cc572c  4003150        8 ...cher.FlowThrottle  0 instance 01fb6760 sessions
    71725030  4003151        c ...her.QuotaThrottle  0 instance 00000000 dynamic
    70cc572c  4003152       10 ...cher.FlowThrottle  0 instance 02013110 instanceContexts
    70cb653c  4003153       14 ...l.ServiceHostBase  0 instance 01fadd84 host
    70cc7cf8  4003154       18 ...manceCountersBase  0 instance 02003590 servicePerformanceCounters
    74246788  4003155       20       System.Boolean  1 instance        1 isActive
    7423f744  4003156       1c        System.Object  0 instance 01fb65cc thisLock
    74242ad4  400314d     1134         System.Int32  1   static      128 DefaultMaxConcurrentCallsCpuCount
    74242ad4  400314e     1138         System.Int32  1   static      800 DefaultMaxConcurrentSessionsCpuCount

    0:032> !do 01fb6660 
    Name:        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.FlowThrottle
    MethodTable: 70cc572c
    EEClass:     70a07d24
    Size:        52(0x34) bytes
    File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    74242ad4  4002ede       20         System.Int32  1 instance     1024 capacity
    74242ad4  4002edf       24         System.Int32  1 instance        0 count
    74246788  4002ee0       2c       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 warningIssued
    74242ad4  4002ee1       28         System.Int32  1 instance       89 warningRestoreLimit
    7423f744  4002ee2        4        System.Object  0 instance 01fb6694 mutex
    74232914  4002ee3        8 ...ding.WaitCallback  0 instance 01fb6640 release
    00000000  4002ee4        c                       0 instance 01fb66a0 waiters
    7423fb08  4002ee5       10        System.String  0 instance 01fb65d8 propertyName
    7423fb08  4002ee6       14        System.String  0 instance 01fb660c configName
    74230f78  4002ee7       18        System.Action  0 instance 02007670 acquired
    74230f78  4002ee8       1c        System.Action  0 instance 02007690 released

    0:032> !do 01fb6760 
    Name:        System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.FlowThrottle
    MethodTable: 70cc572c
    EEClass:     70a07d24
    Size:        52(0x34) bytes
    File:        C:\Windows\Microsoft.Net\assembly\GAC_MSIL\System.ServiceModel\v4.0_4.0.0.0__b77a5c561934e089\System.ServiceModel.dll
    Fields:
          MT    Field   Offset                 Type VT     Attr    Value Name
    74242ad4  4002ede       20         System.Int32  1 instance     1024 capacity
    74242ad4  4002edf       24         System.Int32  1 instance        0 count
    74246788  4002ee0       2c       System.Boolean  1 instance        0 warningIssued
    74242ad4  4002ee1       28         System.Int32  1 instance      560 warningRestoreLimit
    7423f744  4002ee2        4        System.Object  0 instance 01fb6794 mutex
    74232914  4002ee3        8 ...ding.WaitCallback  0 instance 01fb6740 release
    00000000  4002ee4        c                       0 instance 01fb67a0 waiters
    7423fb08  4002ee5       10        System.String  0 instance 01fb66d0 propertyName
    7423fb08  4002ee6       14        System.String  0 instance 01fb6708 configName
    74230f78  4002ee7       18        System.Action  0 instance 020076b0 acquired
    74230f78  4002ee8       1c        System.Action  0 instance 020076d0 released
```

All these values seem to be fine. Then we checked the threadpool and threads:

```
    0:032> !threadpool
    CPU utilization: 0%
    Worker Thread: Total: 1023 Running: 1017 Idle: 6 MaxLimit: 1023 MinLimit: 1000
    Work Request in Queue: 0
    --------------------------------------
    Number of Timers: 4
    --------------------------------------
    Completion Port Thread:Total: 32 Free: 0 MaxFree: 16 CurrentLimit: 33 MaxLimit: 1000 MinLimit: 1000

    0:032> !threads -special
    ThreadCount:      1027
    UnstartedThread:  997
    BackgroundThread: 28
    PendingThread:    997
    DeadThread:       1
    Hosted Runtime:   no
                                       PreEmptive   GC Alloc                Lock
           ID  OSID ThreadOBJ    State GC           Context       Domain   Count APT Exception
       0    1  1d80 006b6518      a020 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA
       2    2  238c 006c1840      b220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Finalizer)
    XXXX    4       00704f58   1019820 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn (Threadpool Worker)
       4    5  21a4 00706480   3009220 Enabled  0bedaf78:0bedb5c8 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
       5    6   e8c 03de9428   100a220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
       7    7   634 03e0d318   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
       8    8  1d38 03ebeb08   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
       9    9  1808 03e4fd70   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      10    a  1c48 03e50d70   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      11    b  1d88 073be2b0   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      12    c  1c74 073bf2b8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      13    d  1ae4 073c0dc8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      14    e  1818 073c1598   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      15    f  1a58 073c1fa8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      16   10  13e0 073c4bb8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      17   11  1a3c 073c5388   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      18   12  1b5c 03e9ffe0   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      19   13  1b80 03ea04e8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      20   14   900 03ea09f0   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      21   15  1c84 03ea0ef8   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      22   16   da0 03ea1400   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      23   17  13b0 03ea1908   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      24   18  18cc 03ea1e10   3009220 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      25   1a  1008 03ea2820   3009220 Enabled  0bfe03b8:0bfe21c4 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      27   29   bc4 0b041588   1009220 Enabled  0bdd7c3c:0bdd99f8 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      28   3b   ad8 0af7d740   1009220 Enabled  0bf8c0d8:0bf8c1c4 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      29   64   dd8 0ae54890   1009220 Enabled  0bdfbb9c:0bdfd9f8 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      30   2f   440 0b03c010   1009220 Enabled  0be03bf0:0be059f8 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      31   25  2198 0b03f080   1009220 Enabled  0bd6d5b4:0bd6f410 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
      32   63  1b9c 0ae41388   1009220 Enabled  0bdb5b14:0bdb79f8 006ac0b0     0 MTA (Threadpool Worker)
    XXXX   33  2270 0b09cd20      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn
    XXXX   5b  1554 0ae54388      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 MTA
    XXXX   31  1098 0ae53978      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn
    XXXX   34   15c 0af7be18      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn
    ... -> lots of more threads here
    XXXX  403  24e4 0d85b578      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn
    XXXX  404  24d8 0d85ba80      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn
    XXXX  405  24e0 0d85bf88      1400 Enabled  00000000:00000000 006ac0b0     0 Ukn

           OSID     Special thread type
        1    a88    DbgHelper 
        2   238c    Finalizer 
        4   21a4    ThreadpoolWorker 
        5    e8c    Timer 
        7    634    ThreadpoolWorker 
        8   1d38    ThreadpoolWorker 
        9   1808    ThreadpoolWorker 
       10   1c48    ThreadpoolWorker 
       11   1d88    ThreadpoolWorker 
       12   1c74    ThreadpoolWorker 
       13   1ae4    ThreadpoolWorker 
       14   1818    ThreadpoolWorker 
       15   1a58    ThreadpoolWorker 
       16   13e0    ThreadpoolWorker 
       17   1a3c    ThreadpoolWorker 
       18   1b5c    ThreadpoolWorker 
       19   1b80    ThreadpoolWorker 
       20    900    ThreadpoolWorker 
       21   1c84    ThreadpoolWorker 
       22    da0    ThreadpoolWorker 
       23   13b0    ThreadpoolWorker 
       24   18cc    ThreadpoolWorker 
       25   1008    ThreadpoolWorker 
       26   1b08    Gate 
       27    bc4    ThreadpoolWorker 
       28    ad8    ThreadpoolWorker 
       29    dd8    ThreadpoolWorker 
       30    440    ThreadpoolWorker 
       31   2198    ThreadpoolWorker 
       32   1b9c    ThreadpoolWorker
```

We were shocked when we saw this amount of threads. Now we suspect that our problem might have something to do with the high number of threads. So if anybody can answer the following questions that would be much appreciated:

1. Could our assumption be correct? Or are we on the wrong track investigating the threads?
2. The !threadpool command outputs a very high number of running threads (1027). Looking at the output from !threads, it seems that only 28 threads are working. How can these differences be explained?
3. We have a very high number of unstarted / pending threads. What is the difference between an unstarted and a pending thread? We tried to reproduce this behavior, but even with setting the minimum and maximum threads in the threadpool we don't get these high numbers. Even more, investigating a dump created after 2 hours of process uptime, no unstarted or pending threads are found (service was still working at this time). The process uptime of the orginal dump was about 14 days.
4. What does the completion port thread free value of 0 mean?
5. Are there any other methods / commands in WinDBG we could use to better understand our problem?

We are very unhappy with the current state of our software, and looking for information regarding this topic most often says it is a unclosed session / concurrent calls issue, but as stated before this doesn't seem to be our problem. Any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: It seems we have similar issue. [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36644902/big-number-of-unstarted-threads-in-net-application). Did you find the reason?

Answer (score 1):

We experienced a similar issue with a self-hosted WCF interface which provided a synchronous request/response web service for an asynchronous (2 one way service calls) backend request.  Early in our testing, we noticed that after a somewhat variable number of days, our service became unresponsive to new requests.  After some research, we discovered that whenever the backend service (out of our control) did not send a response, we continued to wait indefinitely and as such we kept our client connection open.

We fixed the issue by providing a “time-to-wait” configuration value so we were sure to respond to the client and close the connection.  We used something like the following …

```
Task processTask = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => Process(message));

bool isProcessSuccess = processTask.Wait(shared.ConfigReader.SyncWebServiceWaitTime);

if (!isProcessSuccess)
{ 
 //handle error … 
}
```

The following link, which provides information regarding WCF Service performance counters, may help further determine if the calls are being closed as expected.  http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/idof/archive/2011/08/11/wcf-scaling-check-your-counters.aspx